# NSString assignment, release required?

Tags: objective-c

If I have a property in my class like so:\

```
@interface Test

NSString *str;

@end
```

And in my init in the .m:

```
str = @"Test";
```

Do I need to manually release that in the classes dealloc?

What about this kind?

```
NSString *myStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someString];
```

Do I need to release that too?

Comment: To answer the replies below, I'm coding for the iPad, so not sure if I'm using ARC or not...

Comment: You can turn ARC support on and off. It's "ON" by default in the new tools. If you are able to call `retain` or `release` explicitly, the ARC is "OFF"; otherwise, it's "ON".

Answer (score 2):

You should really just use ARC, but to answer your specific question, no: you don't need to release those. You only release what you "own", and you only own things you got from a method that contains one of [`new`, `alloc`, `retain`, `copy`].

That said, since you don't own those strings, you should retain (or copy) them if you need them to stick around.

Comment: So by setting str = @"Test";, for that to persist beyond the scope of the init method, I have to [str retain] it?

Comment: Technically, constant strings like that live in your app's data section, and always exist. In that very special case, you'll be okay not retaining it, but retaining it doesn't hurt, and you should strive for consistency. It's better to just always retain than to think about special cases every time.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to release if you are using ARC in your project (Automatic Reference Counting).  ARC is enabled for iOS 5+ so if you are targeting iOS 5 or higher, you dont have to release anything.

Comment: Just as an aside, you can use ARC back to iOS 4.3 officially (but it will work on earlier versions as well, it's just not officially supported). The only construct that requires iOS 5.0+ is the `__weak` type identifier, since it requires runtime support.

Comment: I'm targeting 4.0 according to my project settings. If I was targetting 5.0, what do you mean by "dont have to release anything"??

Comment: when targeting 5.0, Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) is used which is a form of garbage collection.  There's tons of articles explaining how all of it works. http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1 is a pretty good one.

Answer (score 1):

Both constructs<sup>1</sup> create autoreleased strings. You need to `retain` them (explicitly or by assigning to a retained property), otherwise you will end up with dangling references once the autorelease is called<sup>2</sup>. Once you call a `retain` on an object, releasing it becomes your responsibility.

A more robust approach with `NSString`s is to use `copy` properties, rather than retaining them. Doing so lets you avoid issues when a `NSMutableString` passed into your `init` method gets mutated after you have validated its content.

---

<sup>1</sup> I am assuming that you are asking about pre-ARC version of Objective C tools; otherwise, you will not be able to call `retain` or `release` explicitly.

<sup>2</sup> This usually happens some time after you exit from the method, and the control passes back to the run loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure if you're using ARC or not, just try to release/retain. If it shows a warning saying you can't release/retain, ARC is enabled, else is disabled and you'll have to retain & release.

Comment: Appears that ARC is disabled for me by default. I'm using a project template from the Cocos2D game engine.